# Is date 18+ years old?

Tags: javascript, datetime, validation

Considering that:

- the passed parameters are all numbers
- the passed date is a valid date

It should return:

- `true` if the date is 18 or more years old
- `false` otherwise

---

```
function isDate18orMoreYearsOld(day, month, year) {
    var maxBirthDate = new Date();
    maxBirthDate = new Date(maxBirthDate.setYear(maxBirthDate.getYear() - 18));
    var maxYear = maxBirthDate.getYear();
    var maxMonthOnMaxYear = maxBirthDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var maxDayOnMaxMonthOnMaxYear = maxBirthDate.getDate();
    if (year > maxYear) {
        return true;
    }
    if (year == maxYear) {
        if (month > maxMonthOnMaxYear) {
            return true;
        }
        if (month == maxMonthOnMaxYear) {
            if (day >= maxDayOnMaxMonthOnMaxYear) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Despite I don't want to lose maintainability and readability, I feel it could possibly have a lesser number of conditional statements.

Is there any improvement you suggest?

Also, if you spot any cases that the function fails it's very welcome.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your [tag:performance] and [tag:portability] concerns?

Comment: @200_success Nice point! I actually tagged it [tag:optimization] and [tag:cross-browser], but it was weirdly automatically retagged to [tag:performance] and [tag:portability], which are very distinct terms IMO. I was making a note here to ask it on meta later on. (Despite I'm unsure about [tag:optimization] usage, my intent was to tag with something like shortening, or refactoring, but [tag:optimization] was the closest term I found - if you have any suggestion I'd appreciate your guidance!).

Comment: If you're just looking for a general shortening, don't bother tagging it as such — it's implied in every question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about this:

```
function isDate18orMoreYearsOld(day, month, year) {
    return new Date(year+18, month-1, day) <= new Date();
}
```

The `month - 1` is required because JS months start at 0.

Comment: Seems great, but, is it cross-browser?

Comment: why shouldn't it? `Date` should be available in all browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the constructor. I know some `Date` constructors aren't fully supported on all browsers. I'm just not sure which one.

Comment: Found out! The `new Date(year, month, date)` is [EcmaScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1)! Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Very clever, btw: it passed all corner cases I've tested, including some leap year validations.

Comment: Yes, that's the good thing about using the Date class. All those special cases are handled for you. You only have to compare the dates.